# Fluent validation Vary object validator according to the class it's used in

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have a class which gets reused in multiple places. It has a default validator applied to it, which has the following attribute,  [Validator(typeof(ChildValidator))].

I wanted to be to override the validator that's been applied to Child class depending on the parent class that's using it. Below is a simplified version of my model. So instead of validate Child with ChildValidator, I want to apply rules in ChildValidator2.  Can this be done?

Note: the follow code will always fail the validation because it will always apply rule in ChildValidator

Models:

```
    [Validator(typeof(ParentValidator))]
    public class Parent
    {
        public bool IgnoreChild { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

        public Child Children { get; set; }
    }

    [Validator(typeof(ChildValidator))]
    public class Child
    {
        public string ChildProperty{ get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
```

Validators:

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent>
{
    public ParentValidator()
    {
         RuleFor(model => model.Name).NotEmpty();

         When(x=>x.IgnoreChild, () =>
         {
             RuleForEach(model => model.Child).SetValidator(new ChildValidator2());
         });
    }
}

public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
    public ChildValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.ChildProperty).NotEmpty();
        //Compare birthday to make sure date is < Parents birthday
    }
}



public class ChildValidator2 : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
    public ChildValidator2()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.ChildProperty).Empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Compare birthday to make sure date is < Parents birthday" remided "Don't Be a Menace to South Central While Drinking Your Juice in the Hood" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you debug FluentValidation source code, you will see that `AttributedValidatorFactory` works only for parameters of controller action (`Parent`), not it's child property classes (`Child`). If you didn't applied validator by `SetValidator()` method - no validation actions would be performed. So, your experiment results could be caused by another reason, not one you though.

Try to specify validators explicitly for both values of `IgnoreChild` flag:

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent>
{
    public ParentValidator()
    {
         RuleFor(model => model.Name).NotEmpty();

         When(x=> x.IgnoreChild, () =>
         {
             RuleForEach(model => model.Child).SetValidator(new ChildValidator2());
         });
         When(x=> !x.IgnoreChild, () =>
         {
             RuleForEach(model => model.Child).SetValidator(new ChildValidator());
         });
    }
}
```